# Can I use "if" in a structure that doesn't correspond to the four rules?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

I have a problem with how to use "IF" , Although I know the Rules and so on but when I use it I figure out that I use another IF rule, not from the four rules of IF and can I use it negative in the past ? and it will still be in the four rules ?

I have tried to read the rules again and stick with the rules but somehow I use the only half rule like " I will make it . IF you do that " is that even correct ?

Comment: What are the "four rules of *if*" that you mention? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: If by *rules for if* you mean *conditional sentences*, there are more than four types of conditional sentences (for instance there's past real conditional). In addition there are many more than four ways to construct conditional sentences; there are probably two dozen or more. That's one reason EFL teachers and books "dumb it down" to four types.

Comment: You can rearrange it as "if you do that, I will make it". What do you think is odd about this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about [this](http://www2.estrellamountain.edu/faculty/stonebrink/ESL040/4_types_of_conditionals.htm).

[image]

> somehow I use the only half rule like " I will make it. If you do that." is that even correct ?

Either clause can be omitted from a sentence if it can be pulled from context, which is what you are doing, so it's fine.